# What's the escape key-sequence for System.Console.In.ReadToEnd?

Tags: .net, console

I tried using System.Console.In.ReadToEnd (for [code-golf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), as it happens), but I can't work out what the key sequence is to get it to return from the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl+Z signals end-of-stream when typed in a console window interactively.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file

(Ctrl+Z has to be entered on a new line, and followed by enter)

Comment: +1: FYI: For whatever reason I have to press enter before it will pickup the CTRL+Z (granted it stops reading after it hits CTRL+Z)

Comment: I think the enter is because console input gives you an opportunity to edit a line it is sent to standard in

Comment: The Ctrl+Z has to be on a new line, and followed by an Enter, I've edited and accepted the answer accordingly. I can't find this documented anywhere though.

Comment: That's good to know, I've always put it on a new line, but I never knew it was required. It's just something another programmer taught me back when the command prompt was DOS.